# Comment traduire « alleged murder plot » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, prépositions, ordre-des-mots

La phrase que j'essaye traduire :

> an alleged murder plot

J'envisage quelques possibilités, mais je ne suis pas sûr.

> un complot de meurtre présumé
>
> un complot présumé de meurtre
>
> un complot présumé pour meurtre
>
> un complot pour meurtre présumé

Ce qui est difficile pour moi :

1. Où est-ce qu'on place l'adjectif ?
2. Le choix de préposition (de, pour).
3. Le mot « complot » me semble être un mot canadien car les résultats sur Google pour ces phrases proviennent tous de sites canadiens.

J'ai besoin de précision concernant ces trois aspects.

Comment: Contexte: La phrase vient du journal.

Comment: Une preuve supplémentaire ici de l'adage suivant : on ne traduit que des phrases, pas des expressions. L'unité de sens est la phrase. Simple remarque.

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une phrase, mais un fragment. Vue l'envergure de sens du mot *plot*, il est illusoire de vouloir la traduire sans contexte. Donne-nous la phrase complète, et suffisamment de contexte pour savoir de quel type de *plot* il s'agit.

Comment: Full sentence : "The jury will hear about an alleged murder plot in this court case."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Alleged* me semble mieux être rendu par *prétendu* plutôt que *présumé* (dont l'usage commun est réduit aux contextes juridiques mais fait hurler tous les juristes de ma connaissance qui le disent employé à contre-sens).

Pour *plot*, la difficulté est autre.  Le champs sémantique en anglais est grand. *Complot*, *intrigue* supposent plusieurs personnes et ont une connotation politique forte. *Manœuvre*, *manigance*, *machination*, *plan* même sont aussi possibles. *Plan* a l'avantage d'avoir un grand champs sémantique et peu de connotation, tout comme *plot*.

Finalement, *murder* devrait dans ce contexte être rendu plutôt par *assassinat* (qui demande la préméditation, ce qu'un *plot* implique naturellement) que *meurtre* (qui suppose qu'il y ait volonté de donner la mort mais pas préméditation).  *Assassinat* a l'avantage aussi d'avoir un verbe correspondant qui se met plus facilement qu'un nom comme complément de certaines traductions de *plot*, du moins si on se permet de préciser la victime.

Je suggère donc *un prétendu plan d'assassinat*.

(Ceci écrit, l'usage canadien peut être différent).

Answer (score 3):

Si je comprends bien, *an alleged murder plot* doit être découpé ainsi *[alleged]* (présumé) et *[murder plot]* ou donc seulement *plot* (complot). Donc ce qu'on présume est le complot pour meurtre, et non le meurtre comme tel.

Ensuite, comme on complote dans le but de faire quelque chose, on complote *pour* quelque chose.

Pour bien illustrer le sens qu'on veut lui donner, la phrase serait donc :

> un complot présumé pour meurtre

ou, une tournure encore valide (tournure qui pourrait être utilisée par un journaliste, par exemple (par exemple chez à l'antenne de radio-canada)) :

> un présumé complot pour meurtre

En résumé :

1. Pour faciliter la lecture, on place l'adjectif près du nom auquel il s'attache.
2. On choisit *pour* à cause du sens du mot complot.
3. Si *plot* est utilisé dans le sens *A secret plan to achieve an end, the end or means usually being illegal or otherwise questionable.* ([wiktinoary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plot)), le mot *complot* est approprié.

Comment: En fait « complot présumé pour meurtre » est peut-être la formulation la plus ambiguë. On pourrait comprendre que la présomption porte sur la nature du complot. Je ne sais pas si « complot pour meurtre présumé » est utilisé (j'aurais tendence à l'éviter) mais au moins ça ne me parait pas ambigu. Un complot pour « meurtre présumé » n'ayant a priori aucun sens.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, voilà la raison pour laquelle c'est difficile à traduire. J'aime « un présumé complot pour meurtre », mais je ne veux pas utiliser un calque de structure. La phrase vient d'un article journalistique alors si cette traduction n'est pas un calque ainsi qu'elle est acceptée dans le français standard du Canada (ou le français standard international), je pourrais l'utiliser. Le fait qu'un journaliste le dit chez à l'antenne de radio-canada ne signifie toujours qu'on peut l'écrire.

Comment: Probablement qu'avoir la phrase originale complète aiderait, mais on pourrait améliorer un peu la façon de faire la phrase traduite : *On présumait d'un complot pour meurtre.* - *Il était soupçonné de comploter pour commettre un meurtre.*

Answer (score 1):

I would say

Un prétendu complot de meurtre

In fact the word alleged is qualifying the plot, which happens to be a murder plot.

Answer (score 1):

Bien que le contexte soit manquant pour pouvoir proposer une réelle traduction (car je suis d'accord, on ne peut pas traduire un fragment de phrase sans celle-ci et assez de contexte pour se mettre en situation), si la phrase initiale est "The jury will hear about an alleged murder plot in this court case", on peut proposer:

> Le jury devra examiner [les preuves] au sujet d'une affaire que l'on
>   soupçonne être un complot pour meurtre

Je me suis permis d'ajouter quelques éléments à la phrase car j'imagine qu'ils figurent dans le contexte général que nous n'avons pas pour proposer une traduction plus pertinente!